# AUCTeX user Macros

Tags: macros, auctex

I know that I can add my private macros to auto-completion feature of AUCTeX by running `TeX-auto-generate`. However the macros that AUCTeX "knows" seem to work better i.e. it automatically ask for the arguments of macros that it knows. How can I customize AUCTeX so that it also ask for arguments of my macros? It suffices when AUCTeX prompts for arguments. I don't want to type for each macro that I have what the argument means.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way is to write style files, as described in the manual: https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Style-Files  Usually I start from the one created with `TeX-auto-generate` and tweak it.